# heap sort - which heap (min/max) to use for ascending and descending order sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

I'm noticing a very peculiar thing.

After going through this [lecture](http://video.mit.edu/watch/introduction-to-algorithms-lecture-4-heaps-and-heap-sort-14154/), I implemented some code for heap-sort in C++.

The code is below.

```
    template<typename T> void min_heapify(std::vector<T> &vec, int i, int size)
    {
        int left  = (2*i); //left child of a zero-indexed heap (array)
        int right = (2*i)+1; //right child.
        int min;

        min = ( (left<size) && (vec[left] < vec[i]) ) ? left : i;
        min = ( (right<size) && (vec[right] < vec[min]) ) ? right : min;

        if (min!= i)
        {
            swapper(vec[i],vec[min]);
            min_heapify(vec, min, size);
        }
    }
    template<typename T> void build_min_heap(std::vector<T> &vec, int size)
    {
        int i = size/2;
        while(i--)
        {
            min_heapify(vec, i, size);

        }
    }
    template<typename T> void heap_sort(std::vector<T> &vec, int size)
    {
        // build min heap
        build_min_heap(vec, size);
        // then extract min repeatedly.
        while(size>0)
        {
            size--;
            swapper(vec[0],vec[size]);
            min_heapify(vec,0,size);
        }
    }

   int main()
   {
        vector<int> v{14,-1,1000, -999, 3,2,5,10};
        heap_sort(v, v.size());

        return 0;
   }
```

The peculiar thing is that it makes sense to me that 
- build a min heap
- extract min (or executing min-heapify at the root after building a min heap)
should result in *ascending order*.
However, after executing this code and printing out the resultant vector, 
I get :

```
1000 14 10 5 3 2 -1 -999
```

while trying to make sense of what is going on, I changed

```
min = ( (left<size) && (vec[left] < vec[i]) ) ? left : i;
min = ( (right<size) && (vec[right] < vec[min]) ) ? right : min;
```

to

```
min = ( (left<size) && (vec[left] > vec[i]) ) ? left : i;
min = ( (right<size) && (vec[right] > vec[min]) ) ? right : min;
```

which actually ends up selecting the bigger(or maximum) of the parent and child nodes, and the resultant vector is :

```
-999 -1 2 3 5 10 14 1000
```

Am I doing something wrong or is my understanding of heap/heap sort unclear? What am I missing here?

Comment: Your understanding of heap usage in heapsort may be less than effective: the values conventionally get selected last to first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the `swapper(vec[0],vec[size]);` is the extraction. 
You are extracting the first element into the last element of the vector. Hence getting the opposite result.

The heaps min element is `vec[0]`. Swapping that to the last position will create a max to min ordering within that vector.

If you implement something like

```
result.push_back(heap.pop_min());
```

You will get the ordering you were expecting.

Comment: *"You are supposed to extract by ... (pushing into a result vector)"* -- Are you? That sounds like unnecessary work if what you want is an in-place sort. You should instead change your expectation about how heap sort is supposed to work, and if you want the result to be reversed, then use the reverse comparison.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for the comment. I'll revise.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Hi, does that mean, that I should resort to using the max-heapify in order to do- ascending order sort in-place?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Ah! Of course. If I'm just swapping without taking it out, they're (the min elements) sitting in the array. Thank you.

Comment: @Raaj: Yes, I think so. This is the same thing you would get if, for example, you used the standard library functions `make_heap` followed by `sort_heap`. `make_heap` makes a max heap by default, and `sort_heap` will sort that heap in ascending order.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley
If I were to resort to doing an in-place heap sort, it does make sense. Thanks! 

For those dropping by and trying to make sense of it, please read -  http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs2321/www/newLectures/09_Inplace_Heap_Sort.html for further explanation.